# Prevent Overwriting Current Version in Wiki

Tags: versioning, wiki, settings

Is there any way to prevent a user that is able to read/write the wiki in SharePoint from overwriting the current version?

When I go to check in a version of a wiki page, I am presented with the below dialog.

[image: Check In Screen]

I would like to be able to limit the options to the first two and disable/remove the option that reads

> Overwrite the current minor version

Comment: I would say use jQuery to hide that radio button on the Checkin.aspx page, but that is the same page for all lists, and my usual tricks for opening in edit mode cause an error. So I think modifying the page is a dead-end, unless you want to try using SharePoint Designer. Is the option of training your users to not choose the third radio button not an option here?

Comment: @CigarDoug I have discussed not using the Overwrite the current version option and they are in agreement. I would prefer enforcing our agreement especially for anyone that joins the team later.

Comment: I found a solution for you, posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution here, it involves editing the Checkin.aspx page. This would affect every site collection in the farm, unless you wrap it in a feature.

- Open Windows Explorer to C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS.
- Locate the file "checkin.aspx" and make a copy in case there is a problem.
- Open "checkin.aspx" in SharePoint Designer or editor of your choice.
- Comment out the following lines (164 through 170):

  ```
   <asp:PlaceHolder id="CheckinOverWriteOption" Visible="False" runat="server">
      <TR>
       <TD><INPUT type="radio" id="ActionCheckinOverwrite" onclick="EnableKeepCheckout(this.form);" name="CheckinActionRG"></TD>
           <TD class="ms-authoringcontrols"><asp:Label id="CheckinOverWriteVersion" runat="server" /></TD>
           <TD class="ms-authoringcontrols"><label for="ActionCheckinOverwrite"><SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="<%$Resources:wss,checkin_Overwrite%>" EncodeMethod=’HtmlEncodeAllowSimpleTextFormatting’/></label></TD>
          </TR>
          </asp:PlaceHolder>
  ```

This will hide the radio button that allows a user to overwrite the current minor version.  Now, all changes are tracked individually.  This combined with removing the discard checkout option, means that any time a user wants to edit a file, it will keep a new copy of that file.

http://slingeronline.wordpress.com/2008/09/25/remove-overwrite-current-minor-version-in-publishing-libraries/

Comment: Can you summarize the solution outlined in the link so that this answer can stand on its own with the link existing as a reference? http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/189763

Comment: Cleaned up post from original. Want to ensure I credit "Slinger".